# How to reload flexslider after slider is refreshed with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flexslider

My slider is working when the page loads.

Then i make an ajax call and return new slides inside the slider and it gets deactivated (ofcourse)
[image]

Is there a way to reinitiate the flexslider so that it starts again with the other images?

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself.

Edited the Done function of my ajax call to reinitiate the slider.

```
}).done(function(response){
    $('.slider-wrapper').html(response);
    $('.slider-wrapper .flexslider').flexslider();
});
```